# Как подписать xml-запрос файлом закрытого ключа .key?

Tags: java, криптография

С помощью Крипто-КОМ 3.3 (ГОСТ Р34.10-2001) сгенерирован ключ в формате СКЗИ .key, для него  УЦ выдал там сертификат .cer. 
Мне нужно xml - запрос подписать закрытым ключом - как сделать это средствами java непонятно.

P.S. Пробовал с помощью пакета openssl поместить ключ с сертификатом в формат .pfx, тогда хотя бы было понятно как с этим работать, но запрос вида

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey 00000001.key -in cert.cer -out final_result.pfx
```

Выдает ошибку: Expecting ANY PRIVATE KEY. Как я понимаю, openssl не воспринимает ключ в таком формате.

Как вообще работать с ключом в таком формате?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оставил вопрос на форуме производителя, в руководствах, скорее всего, есть вся нужная информация

http://forum.signal-com.ru/viewtopic.php?f=583&t=2746